# How to convert a complex string to a list / array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I know using `myString.split(",");` would work if I just had a string separated by commas like `"a", "b", "c"`, but what if I have a more complicated string like:

> ["Meal End",  "meal-end", "menu", {"color":"black", "width":1}]

I want to separate out the elements

> "Meal End"
>
> "meal-end"
>
> "menu"
>
> {"color":"black", "width":1}

My first approach was to get a substring of that whole thing from (1 to string.length - 1). That removed the [ ]. Then I used string.split(",") which almost worked... but for element 3 I end up with  {"color":"black" which I do not want.

I want the whole curly brackets object. How can I do this, other than manually searching through the whole string, stopping when I find a {, and continuing when I get to }?

I considered using JSONObject but my string is enclosed in [ ] ... I could always replace those with  { } but then there's no key still...

Comment: Are you actually dealing with JSON?

Comment: The class you're looking for is `JSONArray`.

Comment: @Makoto: No I'm not. I just figured it might be an easier way to extract the elements I want.

Comment: Regex. `split` method actually takes regex pattern.

Comment: Depending on the parsing rules you want to use on your string, 'split' might or might not work. So, you need to present your syntactic rules first. The rest depends.  You might be able to use regex, or you need to traverse the string char by char.

Comment: @shmosel: that worked! Thank you very much. I just convert my [...] line to a json array and get elements 0, 1, 2, and 3

Comment: @shmosel: care to put your answer as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "jackson". It parses this string as a list containing 3 strings and 1 map.

```
List<?> value = (List<?>) new ObjectMapper().readValue(
    "[\"Meal End\", \"meal-end\", \"menu\", {\"color\":\"black\", \"width\":1}]", 
    Object.class);
System.out.println(value.get(0));
Map<?, ?> map = (Map<?, ?>) value.get(3);
System.out.println(map.get("color"));
```

Output:

```
Meal End 
black
```